# GitHub Pages build failure due to "nil was passed to a date-related filter that expects valid dates in atom.xml"

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

On my Jekyll page I get this error once I commit to GitHub:

> The page build failed with the following error:
>
> The value 'nil' was passed to a date-related filter that expects valid dates in `atom.xml` or one of its layouts.

Any idea how to fix it? I went through all posts and checked the Front Matter but can't find anything wrong...

Comment: If you provide the repo URL (or even the contents of `atom.xml`) it'd be much easier to find the issue. Here's the relevant GitHub troubleshooting article: https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-date-is-not-a-valid-datetime/. They suggest running it locally to see the real error.